# What are Github Project Pages and how to use them?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am confused about Github "project pages". How are they different from the "user pages"?

I am using Github Pages for my personal website with custom domain. I'd like to add another site to it like this http://serhii-css.com/my-other-website, like another repository. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: For anyone coming from google and seeking the answer to the question in the title: "project" pages are gh-pages sites associated with a specific repo, where as "user/organization" pages are gh-pages sites associated with a whole user or organization. So you can have multiple project pages per user/org, but (presumably) only one user/org page. See here: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

1. Got to github.com
2. Create a new repository (for example "new-project")
3. Got to the setting of this repository
4. In the "Github Pages" section make sure to have "master branch" or "gh-pages" selected under "Source"
5. Now your new repository will be available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/new-project`

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to keep a consistent theme across the two sites? I want to keep my navbar and such from the parent site on all my project pages.