# Host multiple GitHub websites

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have three static web projects that I would like to host on my GitHub account.
I noticed in the documentation that you have to write your username for a repo name in order to tell GitHub that this will be a static web-site (ex. `bluebird/bluebird.github.io`).

Is it possible to host my projects with different name other than my username?

Comment: The simple solution would be to have multiple github accounts. The URL that you use to access these projects will always be associated with the user that 'owns' them.

Comment: I would be surprised if there isn't a solution for this right now.

Comment: How about hosting them on an organization account?

Comment: I will consider that option. The other solution would be to create a totally new account for just this website.

Comment: Yes - that was my suggestion in the first comment.

Comment: You can also purchase a domain name and add a `CNAME` record to each repo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want three separate `.github.io` URLs, like this:

- https://foo.github.io
- https://bar.github.io
- https://baz.github.io

...then you have no other choice but create one separate GitHub account for each site.
Obviously you can have only one `http:/username.github.io` URL per username :-)

---

But there's another solution: you can have one static page for each repository.
This is called [Project Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages).

You can create three repositories, one per static site you want:

- https://github.com/username/site1
- https://github.com/username/site2
- https://github.com/username/site3

Follow the [instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages) and you can have three static sites with URLs like this:

- https://username.github.io/site1
- https://username.github.io/site2
- https://username.github.io/site3

Comment: Actually, the Project Pages is is the solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: This post explains what to do clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228787/what-are-github-project-pages-and-how-to-use-them